# c++ (sys/socket.h) client retry connect to server leads to seg fault

Tags: c++, sockets, c++14

**Solved**

Thanks to the comment by user4581301 I started to check all the unique_ptr's and discovered that a std::unique_ptrstd::thread wasn't correct in the destructor.

**Original Post:**

(apologies for my bad english)

I'm building a client<->server system in c++ with "sys/socket" where the "user" starts the server and the clients will be running "always".

What I mean is the client will try to connect within intervals to the server regardless if it is running or not. However when i do it get segmentation fault on the third try to connect to the server. (Yes this is probably bad server-client design).

because server is not needed in this cenario only part of client is shown belove: 
client.cpp ()

```
int main(){
  int port = 8888;
  std::string adr = "127.0.0.1";
  bool run = true
  std::unique_ptr<socketHandler> con;

  while(run){
     con.reset(new socketHandler(adr, port));
     while(con->connected()){
       // do stuff
     }
  }
}

class socketHandler{
public:
   socketHandller(std::string address, int port):
   incomingMessageHandler(new MessageHandler())
    , portNummer(port)
    , address(address)
   {
      if( (this->socketContainer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
         exit(1);
      }

      memset(&this->servAddr, '0', sizeof(this->servAddr));
      this->servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      this->servAddr.sin_port = htons(this->portNummer);

      if( inet_pton(AF_INET, this->address.c_str(), &this->servAddr.sin_addr) <= 0){
         exit(1);
      }

      /**
       * The third time this "connect" is "excuted" I get seg fault
       * if it failed on the two first. It does not even call the 
       * "closeSocket" function.
      */
      if(connect(this->socketContainer, (struct sockaddr*)&this->servAddr, sizeof(this->servAddr)) < 0){
         closeSocket();
         return; 
      }

      // More stuff
   }

   bool connected(){
     // return true if "test-message" been received from server.
   }

   // skiped some functions as well

private:
    void closeSocket(){
       close(this->socketContainer);
       this->socketContainer = 0;
    }

   int portNummer;
   std::string address;
   std::atomic<int> socketContainer;
   struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
   std::atomic<bool> connectStatus;
}
```

I feel this was the only "code" that has with the problem to do so not everything is there I'll give more if necessary.

From what I found in terms of documentation I feel where lost and what I found in all the examples online on the sys/socket they all to Exit(1) on the failed "connect()" call, but no real reason why.

Do anyone here know why this is happening? And/Or has a way to "fix" this problem?

Some links:

- https://linux.die.net/man/2/connect
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/
- [http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/practical/](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/%7Edonahoo/practical/CSockets/practical/)

Thanks for your help.

**Solution:**

privous (seg fault destructor):

```
int main(){
  int port = 8888;
  std::string adr = "127.0.0.1";
  bool run = true
  std::unique_ptr<socketHandler> con;

  while(run){
     con.reset(new socketHandler(adr, port));
     while(con->connected()){
       // do stuff
     }
  }
}

class socketHandler{
public:
   socketHandller(std::string address, int port):
   incomingMessageHandler(new MessageHandler())
    , portNummer(port)
    , address(address)
   {
      if( (this->socketContainer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
         exit(1);
      }

      memset(&this->servAddr, '0', sizeof(this->servAddr));
      this->servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      this->servAddr.sin_port = htons(this->portNummer);

      if( inet_pton(AF_INET, this->address.c_str(), &this->servAddr.sin_addr) <= 0){
         exit(1);
      }

      /**
       * The third time this "connect" is "excuted" I get seg fault
       * if it failed on the two first. It does not even call the 
       * "closeSocket" function.
      */
      if(connect(this->socketContainer, (struct sockaddr*)&this->servAddr, sizeof(this->servAddr)) < 0){
         closeSocket();
         return; 
      }

      msgRecvThrd.reset(new std::thread(&ClientSocketHandler::receiveMessagesFromSocket, this));
   }

   bool connected(){
     // return true if "test-message" been received from server.
   }

   void receiveMessagesFromSocket(){
      // if incoming message add the messagehandler... (while thread running)
   }

   ~socketHandller(){
      /**
      * THIS CAUSED THE SEG FAULT (obviouse, when thinking about it)
      */
      while(true){
         if(this->msgRecvThrd->joinable()){
           this->msgRecvThrd->join();
           break;
         }
      }
   }


   // skiped some functions as well

private:
    void closeSocket(){
       close(this->socketContainer);
       this->socketContainer = 0;
    }

   int portNummer;
   std::string address;
   std::atomic<int> socketContainer;
   struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
   std::atomic<bool> connectStatus;
   std::unique_ptr<MessageHandler> incomingMessageHandler;
   std::unique_ptr<std::thread> msgRecvThrd;
}
```

Destructor that fixed the seg fault:

```
int main(){
  int port = 8888;
  std::string adr = "127.0.0.1";
  bool run = true
  std::unique_ptr<socketHandler> con;

  while(run){
     con.reset(new socketHandler(adr, port));
     while(con->connected()){
       // do stuff
     }
  }
}

class socketHandler{
public:
   socketHandller(std::string address, int port):
   incomingMessageHandler(new MessageHandler())
    , portNummer(port)
    , address(address)
   {
      if( (this->socketContainer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
         exit(1);
      }

      memset(&this->servAddr, '0', sizeof(this->servAddr));
      this->servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      this->servAddr.sin_port = htons(this->portNummer);

      if( inet_pton(AF_INET, this->address.c_str(), &this->servAddr.sin_addr) <= 0){
         exit(1);
      }

      /**
       * The third time this "connect" is "excuted" I get seg fault
       * if it failed on the two first. It does not even call the 
       * "closeSocket" function.
      */
      if(connect(this->socketContainer, (struct sockaddr*)&this->servAddr, sizeof(this->servAddr)) < 0){
         closeSocket();
         return; 
      }

      msgRecvThrd.reset(new std::thread(&ClientSocketHandler::receiveMessagesFromSocket, this));
   }

   bool connected(){
     // return true if "test-message" been received from server.
   }

   void receiveMessagesFromSocket(){
      // if incoming message add the messagehandler... (while thread running)
   }

   ~socketHandller(){
      /**
      * FIXED
      */
      while(this->msgRecvThrd != nullptr){
         if(this->msgRecvThrd->joinable()){
           this->msgRecvThrd->join();
           this->msgRecvThrd.reset();
         }
      }
   }


   // skiped some functions as well

private:
    void closeSocket(){
       close(this->socketContainer);
       this->socketContainer = 0;
    }

   int portNummer;
   std::string address;
   std::atomic<int> socketContainer;
   struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
   std::atomic<bool> connectStatus;
   std::unique_ptr<MessageHandler> incomingMessageHandler;
   std::unique_ptr<std::thread> msgRecvThrd;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: instead of `con.reset(new socketHandler(adr, port));` give `con = make_unique<socketHandler>(adr, port));` It's slightly safer. The `reset` version could fail in the while disposing of an old `socketHandler` or in the deep magic of the `reset` function and leave you without anyone pointing at the `new socketHandler`.

Comment: FYI, 0 is a valid socket value on some platforms. Use -1 instead to denote an invalid socket (ie, after calling `close()`)

Comment: Nothing segfault-worthy jumps out at me. Probably need an [mcve].